# Type a letter in the jquery chosen live search field, the letter gets disappeared after the suggestion

Tags: jquery, text, livesearch

When I type a letter in the drop-down live search field, the letter gets disappeared after the suggestion `

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.